# Json_decode throws a null array when string contain "&" sign

Tags: php, ios, mobile, laravel-5

I have a problem with the `json_decode()` when passed string contain "&".
When mobile app send a request as a post containing this type of a UTF encoded string:

```
[
  {
    "mobile": [
      "123456"
    ],
    "full_name": [
      "Bride&Groom"
    ]
  }
```

`json_decode()` a null array. This happens when only send the request through the mobile end.
specific scenario?
We are using Laravel 5.

Request taken like this `$friendDetails = $request->friend`
then pass the variable through json_decode

```
$decodedFriend = json_decode($friendDetails ,true);
```

As headers we are using Oauth and header values are like this.

```
Authorization Bearer <token>
```

Content type is `application form data`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function and the string you gave as example is perfectly decoded to:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["mobile"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "123456"
  }
  ["full_name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Bride&Groom"
  }
}
```

Consider adding a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: as i told you, this happens when we get the request from the mobile end

Comment: as I meant in my answer, the problem seems to be not in the JSON format, but somewhere else, for example in HTTP headers and content-type of your mobile client POST or whatever. That's why I asked for MCVE

Comment: what if you chnage the content-type to 'application/json' on the mobile end and request the json data in Laravel with $request->json() method?

Comment: Will try it and let you know

Comment: remove all spacing in the json data on the mobile side. I.e. make it "[{"mobile":["123456"],"full_name":["Bride&Groom"]}]" (without leading/trailing quotes) sent from your mobile app. Also, the initial question contained invalid json, it did not have closing ']', hope that was just a typo. But also do validate the json sent "as-is" from your mobile on jsonlint.com